# My solution is right and the book is wrong (parabolas) or did I misunderstand it?

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions, conic-sections

***Find the equation of the parabola with the vertex at the origin; directrix 2x = 3***

So what I did is, find the equation of the directrix
$$x =  \frac{3}{2}$$
and then because its the directrix, the focus must be 
$$\bigl(-\frac{3}{2},0\bigr)$$
then multiplying it by 4, I get the equation
$$y^2 = -6x$$
I'm correct right? because the book said the answer is $3y^2 = -8x$ and I've checked using graphing softwares that it isn't the same graph as my answer. Graphing softwares don't show the directrix so I can't confirm it. Although I've checked my answer and it seems odd that our textbook is wrong this time.

Comment: The equation of a parabola that opens left/right with vertex at the origin and directrix $x=-p$ is $y^2=4px$. Here, you have $p=-3/2$. So, you're right. It seems the book made an error in division, somehow obtaining $x=2/3$ from $2x=3$...

Comment: @DavidMitra Would you mind putting a version of that comment as an answer so this no longer stays unanswered? If you *would* mind, perhaps goldencalf should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is wrong, you are right. The left opening mouth parabola is $ y^2 = - 4 f x $, so focal length $f =  - \frac32 $ to the left from origin and directrix $ f = x= + \frac32 $ to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your answer is correct. The book might have mentioned it wrong. :)